# How to add a command to my coin-flip Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm new to programming and I've run into a problem.
Here's my code for a simple coin flip simulator:

```
import random
import time

chosen_side = input("Type Heads or Tails: ")
options = ['Heads', 'Tails']
q = (random.choice(options))

if chosen_side == q:
    for x in range (0,5):
        b = "Flipping" + "." * x
        print (b, end="\r")
        time.sleep(0.3)
    time.sleep(0)
    print("-------------")
    print("You have Won!")
    print("--------------")

if chosen_side != q:
    for x in range (0,5):
        b = "Flipping" + "." * x
        print (b, end="\r")
        time.sleep(0.3)
    time .sleep(0)
    print("--------------")
    print("You have Lost!")
    print("--------------")
```

So the code itself works, but I have a list, called "options" ,that contains "Heads" and "Tails" (in line 5). So I want to make it that if you don't type a word out of the 'options' list the coin won't flip and it will tell you "Invalid Input". So basically I want to make it that the coin flip only works if you type 'Heads' or 'Tails' as an input.

Comment: You should read about the `elif` and `else` parts of an `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can add validation after you get the chosen_side

```
chosen_side = input("Type Heads or Tails: ")
options = ['Heads', 'Tails']
if chosen_side.strip().title() not in options:
    raise ValueError('Invalid Input')
    # you can also just print('invalid input') and return if you dont want an error
```

We are using `.strip` and `.title` so `heads` and `tails` and so on are still acceptable. But you could also just check `if chosen_site not in options`.

Answer (score 0):

modesitt's answer is good but it can be improved by adding a while loop where the user can reinput the option if he/she fails with invalid input, something like this:

```
while chosen_side.lower() != 'heads' or chosen_side.lower() != 'tails':
    chosen_side = input('You have entered an invalid input! Please try again\nHeads or 
    tails?\n> ')
```